# PM2: ecosystem.json vs. process.json

Tags: pm2

Reading the PM2 documentation, I've paid attention that in some cases **ecosystem.json** is mentioned, while in other — **process.json**.

How are both these files related to each other and which one should I use for the PM2 configuration?

P.S. Some tutorials refer to the PM2 configuration file as **apps.json**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferred way, as of today is to use a js file, called ecosystem.config.js.

Refer to updated documentation here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Comment: Are there any benefits from using `ecosystem.config.js` over `ecosystem.json`? I've [read](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/pm2-start-multiple-apps-with-a-single-process-file-json-js-yaml) that there are no benefits of deciding for one or another.

Comment: JS configuration like ecosystem.config.js allows you to use javascript to modify some behavior, inject environement variables and so on